# Проблема с отображением пробок на 2 картах от яндекса

Tags: javascript, html, api, yandex-maps-api

На странице создаются 2 карты с разными городами. Сразу с помощью api вывожу на карту слой с пробками с помощью метода showTraffic(). Помимо слоя еще сверху в углу выводится балл пробок. Так вот какая проблема - случается что-то типа коллизии что ли, и в итоге у 2 карт баллы одинаковые, хотя на самом деле они разные. В общем вот скриншот http://imghost.in/image/Filb3 . На скриншоте 2 карты - Санкт-Петербург и Москва и у них по 3 балла, хотя если зайти на yandex maps и проверить эти города по отдельности, то у Петербурга 3 балла, а у Москвы 2 на тот момент. В итоге получается, что балл от Петербурга вставился в обе карты. Как можно решить это?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1.69/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
      ymaps.ready(function() {
      
        var map1 = new ymaps.Map('map1', {
          center: [59.939095, 30.315868],
          controls: ['trafficControl'],
          zoom: 11
        });
        map1.controls.get('trafficControl').showTraffic()
        
        var map2 = new ymaps.Map('map2', {
          center: [55.755814, 37.617635],
          controls: ['trafficControl'],
          zoom: 11
        });
        map2.controls.get('trafficControl').showTraffic()
        
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map1" style="height: 300px; width: 400px;"></div>
    <div id="map2" style="height: 300px; width: 400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно разнести код в два подключения, баг посмотрим, спасибо)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1.69/?lang=ru_RU&ns=ym1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1.69/?lang=ru_RU&ns=ym2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
      ym1.ready(function() {
      
        var map1 = new ym1.Map('map1', {
          center: [59.939095, 30.315868],
          controls: ['trafficControl'],
          zoom: 11
        });
        map1.controls.get('trafficControl').showTraffic()
        
      });
ym2.ready(function() {
        
        var map2 = new ym2.Map('map2', {
          center: [55.755814, 37.617635],
          controls: ['trafficControl'],
          zoom: 11
        });
        map2.controls.get('trafficControl').showTraffic()
        
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map1" style="height: 300px; width: 400px;"></div>
    <div id="map2" style="height: 300px; width: 400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```